# rsync on large file intermittently causes linux to force restart

Tags: crash, rsync, memory-usage

I'm trying to copy a large file (150 GB) via rsync from another server (via `rsync -r FOLDER2COPY username@IPaddress:/local/folder/to/copy/to`)

However, about 1/3 of the way through, my computer always freezes momentarily and then reboots. Using the command `free -h`, I've noted that as the file is transferred (usually from 0 to ~45/150 GB), my cache folder increases to a maximum value of ~52 GB before force shutdown occurs.

I'm currently running CentOS, but a similar problem happened on Ubuntu (I switched OS thinking this might help) whereby the computer froze up entirely, and terminal windows only offered blank lines (commands could be written, but not sent).

I'm preparing to run memtest on this computer next - are there any other suggestions for what could be happening?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: On current Ubuntu, `journalctl -b -1 -e` will show the last messages before the last crash.

Comment: You might need to [enable logs of previous boots](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159390/209677). There is enough space on both sides (`df -h`)? Also check what's going on with `htop` or `glances`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After running Automatic Bug Reporting Tool, the error reported was “kernel crashed - bug: unable to handle kernel paging requests at __ (long list of numbers)”…

After trying numerous things, I eventually ran PassMark Memtest86... and tested each of my memory sticks independently and found one that was erroneous. If anyone else runs into something screwy like this, I highly suggest jumping straight to this test.